# Spring 5.0.1 namedJdbcTemplate batchUpdate ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, ora-01000

I have recently upgraded my project from Spring Framework 4.3.10 to 5.0.1.
After the upgrade the namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate started to fail with this error

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded.

The batch updates 250 records a time which has not changed and was working fine with Spring 4.3.x.

Has anyone came across a similar issue with Spring 5.0.1 ?

I haven't seen any changes in the Spring documentation related to usage of batchUpdate.

Any clues or is it a candidate for jire issue.

I have rolled back spring-jdbc alone to version 4.3.10 which resolved the issue. 
I have also raised a Jira regression defect https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16139

Comment: My oh my why would you have so many cursors opened at once? You should close unused cursors once you done reading you know that right?

Comment: seems often reported with spring, but not after version change https://tomkaspblog.wordpress.com/tag/jdbctemplate/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436436/ora-01000-maximum-open-cursors-exceededwhen-using-spring-simplejdbccall

Answer (score 3):

After exchanging information via Spring JIRA ticket the following resolved the issue:

1. Upgrading to the latest Oracle JDBC driver 12.2.0.1 (ojdbc8.jar)
2. Creating spring.properties file with entry:`spring.jdbc.getParameterType.ignore=true`

The Oracle driver upgrade resolves the cursor leaking issue. The spring.properties file resolves performance issue with spring-jdbc version 5.0.1.

I expect that there will be some changes in spring-jdbc 5.0.2 that will resolve the issue without having to create custom spring.properties file.

**The issue was resolved thanks to Juergen Hoeller from Spring team.**

Comment: is there a spring bug/ticket where they resolved it?

Comment: Where do we need to create the spring.properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the issue was resolved in Spring 5.0.2:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20687

Comment: The spring.properties needs to be added to resources folder. At the same time in spring boot the entry would need to be added to existing application.yaml. With newer version of Spring I don't think the issue is present.